# Insertar datos de un string json

Tags: php, json

Buenas, estoy intentando insertar datos de un `string json`, pero no sé como mostrar solo la información que quiero.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "CategoryId": 41,
    "ParentCategoryId": 0,
    "CategoryGroupId": 4,
    "CategoryName": "Almacenamiento interno",
    "SearchKeys": null,
    "DisplayOrder": 1,
    "IsRootCategory": false
  },
  {
    "CategoryId": 469,
    "ParentCategoryId": 0,
    "CategoryGroupId": 2,
    "CategoryName": "Accesorios Portátil",
    "SearchKeys": null,
    "DisplayOrder": 1,
    "IsRootCategory": false
  }
]
```

Y quiero pasarlo a esto:

```
[
  {
    "CategoryId": 41,
    "CategoryName": "Almacenamiento interno"
  },
  {
    "CategoryId": 469,
    "CategoryName": "Accesorios Portátil",
  }
]
```

Mi problema principal es que no se cómo "quitar" la información que me sobra, o cómo meter la que quiero en otro string json (o array, supongo que a la base de datos no le importa mucho si uso un `foreach`).

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que he intentado:

```
`$contResult = json_decode($contentResult);
$values = array();
foreach ($contResult as $value) {
array_push($values, $value->CategoryName);
}
return $values;`
```

Pero me da un error (`Notice: Array to string conversion`) en la línea 4 de aquí:

```
require 'api/classes/Autoloader.php';

$obj = new Request();
echo $obj->request();
```

He conseguido hacer lo que intentada (casi, al menos). Ahora estoy intentando juntar las keys, esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
    $contResult = json_decode($contentResult);
    $values = array();
    foreach ($contResult as $value) {
        array_push($values, $value->CategoryName);
        array_push($values, $value->CategoryId);
    }
```

Lo que me devuelve lo siguiente `["Almacenamiento interno",41,"Accesorios Portátil",469]`, que casi vendría a ser lo que intento hacer. Cómo puedo separarlos?

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora y los problemas o errores surgidos. Muestranos tu intento de quitar o de mover a otro JSON. Recuerda leer [ask] para hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: Supongo que recibes ese JSON en PHP. ¿De dónde lo recibes, de Javascript, de un servicio REST...?

Comment: @A.Cedano lo recibo de una petición cURL, y va todo bien.

Comment: lo quieres regresar como json? si lo quieres regresar como otro json te falta codificarlo de nuevo, intenta con return json_encode($values);

Comment: @Sergio1871 Era eso! Se me olvidaba codificarlo. Mi problema ahora está en meter CategoryId y CategoryName. He editado mi pregunta con lo que he intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una vez codificado con `json_encode`  cambía tu foreach para agregar con indice

```
foreach ($contResult as $value) {
   $valuesAux = []
   $valuesAux['CategoryName'] = $value->CategoryName;
   $valuesAux['CategoryId'] = $value->CategoryId;
   $values[] = $valuesAux;
}
return json_encode($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Está no sería la mejor forma de hacerlo pero es una de las formas que se puede hacer.

```
<?php 
$json = '[
{
"CategoryId": 41,
"ParentCategoryId": 0,
"CategoryGroupId": 4,
"CategoryName": "Almacenamiento interno",
"SearchKeys": null,
"DisplayOrder": 1,
"IsRootCategory": false
},
{
"CategoryId": 469,
"ParentCategoryId": 0,
"CategoryGroupId": 2,
"CategoryName": "Accesorios Portátil",
"SearchKeys": null,
"DisplayOrder": 1,
"IsRootCategory": false
}
]';


 $json = json_decode($json,true);


unset($json[0]['ParentCategoryId']);
unset($json[0]['CategoryGroupId']);
unset($json[0]['SearchKeys']);
unset($json[0]['DisplayOrder']);
unset($json[0]['IsRootCategory']);

unset($json[1]['ParentCategoryId']);
unset($json[1]['CategoryGroupId']);
unset($json[1]['SearchKeys']);
unset($json[1]['DisplayOrder']);
unset($json[1]['IsRootCategory']);

print_r($json);
 ?>
```

Comment: Hoola Jose. Puedes explicar mejor tu respueta? por qué no es lo mejor lo que el usuario hacia y por qué lo tuyo si?  Mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Con un ciclo puedes evitar repetir la misma operación 2 veces en tu respuesta, además como vas a remover más elementos de los que vas a dejar lo más optimo sería crear uno nuevo agregando lo que deseas

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($contResult as $valor) {
    $reg;
    foreach($valor as $k=>$v){
        if($k=='CategoryName' || $k=='CategoryId'){$reg[$k]=$v;}
    }
    array_push($values,$reg);
}
return json_encode($values);
```

==============================================
**version explicacion**: a pedido de nuestro compañero @lois6b

```
$values = array();
//recorres tus datos, considerando solo el "valor" (no el indice o clave) y que tienes 2 grupos de datos
foreach ($contResult as $valor) {
    //variable array, que almacena datos temporalmente
    $reg;
    //recorres los datos internos (categoryname, categoryid, etc), esta vez considerando clave y valor
    foreach($valor as $k=>$v){
        //si es clave deseada se asigna a array temporal
        if($k=='CategoryName' || $k=='CategoryId'){$reg[$k]=$v;}
    }
    //asignando el array temporal al array principal
    array_push($values,$reg);
}
return json_encode($values);
```

Comment: Es mejor que la explicacion no esté como comentario de codigo si no fuera. Pero como creas que resulte más claro. Puedes tambien usar ambas estrategias ;)

Comment: estoy de acuerdo que es necesario la explicacion, me parecio simple por ser 5 lineas de codigo, pero bueno ahi esta las dos versiones, espero se entienda

Comment: Pero queda muy reduntante. No es mejor explicar fuera de los comentarios y no duplicar el codigo? Es una sugerencia, al fin y al cabo es tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te podría servir la función creada por [Jack P.](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/array_remove_keys/php-array_remove_keys-function-examples.html#0x1698d96d12ddd0a120d60cec3768b4d4cd43e56206518501aae8a2fa6474c9d4-20,,47,), llamada `array_remove_keys`.

Le pasas en parámetro dos arrays, el array con todos los datos, y otro array con las claves que quieres remover.

Si tu array es algo más o  menos así:

```
$arrOriginal=
        array(
                array(
                        "CategoryId"=> 41,
                        "ParentCategoryId"=> 0,
                        "CategoryGroupId"=> 4,
                        "CategoryName"=> "Almacenamiento interno",
                        "SearchKeys"=> null,
                        "DisplayOrder"=> 1,
                        "IsRootCategory"=> false),

                array(
                        "CategoryId"=> 42,
                        "ParentCategoryId"=> 0,
                        "CategoryGroupId"=> 4,
                        "CategoryName"=> "Almacenamiento interno2",
                        "SearchKeys"=> null,
                        "DisplayOrder"=> 1,
                        "IsRootCategory"=> false)
             );
```

Creas un array con las claves que quieres quitar:

```
$arrRemover=array(
                   "ParentCategoryId",
                   "CategoryGroupId",
                   "SearchKeys", 
                   "DisplayOrder",
                   "IsRootCategory"
                 );
```

Y pasas esas dos variables a la función:

```
$arrNuevo = array_remove_keys($arrOriginal, $arrRemover);
var_dump($arrNuevo);
```

La salida (`var_dump`) en este caso será algo así:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["CategoryId"]=>
    int(41)
    ["CategoryName"]=>
    string(22) "Almacenamiento interno"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["CategoryId"]=>
    int(42)
    ["CategoryName"]=>
    string(23) "Almacenamiento interno2"
  }
}
```

Puedes ver un demo completo aquí: **<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/ZPDS13319)</kbd>**